# Updates to error states

Tags: discussion, error-message, responsive-design

We have updated error states for Ask a Question to use a new inline style that works better for smaller screens.

### New error state

[image: New error state]

---

### Old error state

[image: Old error state]

Comment: We've identified a few bugs related to async validation of tags error states. We'll be looking into those.

Comment: Should we report bugs here as answers?

Comment: @Laurel Please do.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

#### Make warning look more prominent.

While this looks really good for errors, it isn't that good for warnings. Check this out:

> [image]

For errors the bold red does provide enough contrast to make it look a bit different and does ensure that the user reads it. Now taking a look at the warnings:

> [image]

This seems to similar to the surrounding text. I get it that most users on Stack Overflow are programmers who don't give a damn to warnings, but having more prominent warnings does help sometimes.

The advantage of the huge blob to the right side was that it was out of place (with the dark background, as compared to the white one now) and called out for attention. Now it just goes below the edit tags space, where the [Submit] button looks more prominent.

(Another way would be to make the [Submit] button verify if the user has read the warning, but I guess that's more work than doing some CSS magic to make it look more prominent)

Comment: On ELL and Japanese, the errors are in red but aren't bolded.  It seems this is not consistent across sites.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

#### Removing a tag does not remove its warning.

On the Ask Question page on Stack Overflow, I added the regex tag, which caused the warning to show, then removed the tag. The warning didn't go away. Then I added the SQL tag, which caused another tag warning to be added. Then I replaced the SQL tag with the PHP tag, ending up with something like this:

> [image]

It doesn't make sense to show warnings for tags that are no longer on the question.

Comment: Yep, this is the bug I referred to above. [meta-tag:status-planned]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Spacing between errors can be weird/confusing

I went on the Ask Question page on Stack Overflow and typed in the title "problem having you seo" and got several errors:

> [image]

At first I thought the bullet points were misaligned, but they're not. It's just that there's a new line in several of the errors that makes it look like the last line is part of the next bullet.

The same thing happens with tags:

> [image]