# No error handling for posting as a guest

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, anonymous-visitors

Trying to post as a guest when **all fields** are empty shows me an error:

> [image: error]

But if I fill **at least one field** (title, body, tags) I see no error message, but infinite processing indicator (I set only one letter ‘q’ for the title):

> [image: processing]

Moreover I can click on the “Post your question” button again and again and will see the following:

> [image: more processing]

Comment: off-topic: I see you rolled back a burnination attempt for the tag guest-posting. I really don't think we need that tag. Can you explain why you so desperately want to hang on to that tag? Without a good reason I'm going to remove it again but I don't fancy getting into a rollback-war over it.

Comment: @rene pretty sure OP here wasn't aware of the existing [tag:anonymous-visitors] tag and wasn't aware of the word anonymous being used hence failed to find it. Based on this assumption, I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 6):

The immediate cause of this is the recent update to [render validation errors inline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315099/updates-to-error-states). Specifically, those snazzy SVG images that validation now sticks to the side of the fields that've failed validation:

> [image: example SVG: an exclamation point in a red circle at the end of the title field]

Yeah, that baby. Turns out, loading SVGs is a bit more tricky than loading, say, a GIF - so there's a tidy pile of JavaScript that gets loaded to handle it. The initialization for this script is a wee bit dicey: on load it pre-pre-initializes constants for all the predefined icons, and then - after the other scripts have loaded - there's an initialization routine that has to be called to finish pre-initializing those constants with a loader routine. Then, upon first use, each icon is actually loaded. And from then on, they're cached. This script is helpfully included in both the scripts loaded for logged-in users *and* the scripts loaded for anonymous users, so it really shouldn't be an issue...

...except that two years ago, someone added a little bit of script to the tag editor to track editing events. And that tiny bit of script loads full.js - the set of scripts normally reserved for logged-in users. It loads those scripts *even if the current user isn't logged in*... Which means when you open any editor with a tag-edit field as an anonymous user, a whole bunch of scripts get loaded *twice*...

...Including that SVG loader...

...Which has a really delicate initialization routine only partially completed on load...

...So now the second instance stomps on the already pre-initialized first instance, leaving it only pre-pre-initialized...

...and thus we get this:

> [image: Error in browser console: "Uncaught Svg icon getters must be initialized before an icon can be retrieved"]

As you might guess, this also affects any anonymous editor trying to suggest an edit to a question on any site (since there's a tag editor there too).